# GroovyWrapper java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: CSVParser

Tags: groovy, noclassdeffounderror

I have a working groovy script - **myscript.groovy**

After using GroovyWrapper: `groovy GroovyWrapper -m myscript -c`

The next step is to run my compiled code: `java -jar myscript.jar`

After running I had an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: CSVParser
    at pro.run(pro.groovy:1963)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1085)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:909) bla-bla-bla ...
```

Here is cut from **myscript.groovy** where I used CSVParser class:

```
def inputPath='D://'

class CSVParser {
    static def parseCSV(file,closure) {
        def lineCount = 0
        file.eachLine() { line ->
            def field = line.tokenize(",")
            lineCount++
            closure(lineCount,field)
        }
    }
}

use(CSVParser.class) {
    filename='filename_for_parsing.txt'
    File file = new File(inputPath,filename)
    if(file.size()>0){
        file.parseCSV { index,field ->
            variable1="${field[0]}"
            variable2="${field[1]}"
            variable3="${field[2]}"
            println variable1
            println variable2
            println variable3                        
        }
    }
}
```

I can't understand: where I was wrong and where did mistake.

Comment: Can You provide a minimal working example?

Comment: I posted working example

Comment: No. You definitely didn't unfortunately. What is `...
some code
...` for instance? By working example I mean sample code ready to copy to console and run.

Comment: Ok, updated answer. See once again if it helps.

Comment: Is it working well right now?

Comment: Thanks to Guillame Laforge! :) You're welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Note*: I've deleted to previous answer as it had nothing to do with the real problem.

Basically the the jar created by GroovyWrapper doesn't work because the `CSVParser` class isn't included into the jar. You can build the jar file and check it with online [decompiler](http://jd.benow.ca/).

The solution is to sligthly modify the build script You use. I've created an [example](https://github.com/Opalo/groovy-wrapper-fail/commits/master) project on GitHub and [twitted](https://twitter.com/SynSzatana/status/490905042317496320) Guillame Laforge to have a look. He helped!

Comment: ok. this script is work. but try to do this: `groovy GroovyWrapper -m myscript -c` and after this: `java -jar myscript.jar`. the problem is that I want compile my groovy script to java jar and it doesn't work with this class. If I'll remove it from my code - all be ok.

Comment: Yes, You're right. It's not working. It seems that classes declared in  the script body are not added to final jar - no idea why. Have tried to put the `CSVParser` class in a separated file and package, but it's not packaged as well. As a workaround You can You use gradle with distribution or application plugin. Maybe will have a look at it later on.